# Use different field for column in subclass of EJB entity

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I need some help with the design of my entities.

I have a single table `MyEntity` with the following columns:

```
id | column1 | column2 | type
```

And the entity looks like:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "type", length = 255)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class MyEntity {

    @id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

I would like to be able to have several entities inheriting from `MyEntity` and where each entity define how they use the columns `column1` and `column2`. I would like to just use one single table for all my subclasses, and use the discriminator.

Like this (the following doesn't work):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TestClass1")
public class TestClass1 extends MyEntity {

    @Column(name = "column1");
    private long testField1;

    @Column(name = "column2");
    private long testField2;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TestClass2")
public class TestClass2 extends MyEntity {

    @Column(name = "column1");
    private long anotherName1;

    @Column(name = "column2");
    private long anotherName2;
}
```

I know this approach is not working, so I am reaching out to you guys for help.

**EDIT**

I have added the inheritance strategy to the `MyEntity` class, but `SINGLE_TABLE` is default, so it shouldn't make a difference.

I have tried two approaches:

1) If I don't put two fields `MyEntity` named `column1` and `column2`, then I cannot create any named queries in `MyEntity` such as:

```
@NamedQuery(name=TEST, query="select m from MyEntity m where m.column1 = :val")
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: column1 of: com.test.MyEntity
```

I would really prefer to specify the queries in `MyEntity` and not in the subclasses.

2) If I put the fields (`column1` and `column2`) in `MyEntity`, then I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.test.TestClass1 column: column1 (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

and I don't know how to move on from here. I'm not sure how to do the mapping, which is suggested in the exception message.

Comment: Try to specify inheritance strategy by `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` in your `MyEntity` entity.

Comment: No, do not try to use "JOINED" because then you would have multiple tables, and the questions says use just one! When you say something "is not working" what does that mean? Why not start by specifying the DiscriminatorColumn annotation on the base entity, and the Inheritance annotation also?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated my post with further info.

Comment: looks like your JPA provider doesn't support it, unless they have some vendor specific option in their docs that allows it (you can't use insertable/updatable since that would break other things)

Comment: Hmmm, too bad. I was pretty confident that this would be possible. We are using Hibernate but I think we are going to use vendor specific options (if there are any that would help).

Comment: Oops...I DON'T think that we are going to vendor specific options. :)